# Python True Random Numbers For Cryptography With Input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a basic encryption program that uses one time pads and I'm wondering how I can generate true random numbers (since that is essential for the encryption to be unbreakable).

I'm planning to use python's `os.urandom()` to generate random numbers for key creation, but I know this is only a PRNG. My question is this: If I were to use a random input in addition to numbers generated by `os.random()` (my thought was a few rolls of a 50 sided die by my desk) and perform some mathematical operations using both sources to generate a random number, would the outputted number then be a true random number?

note: I suppose this question really boils down to whether or not the roll of a die can be considered a source of true randomness. I found the following article, but let's assume I purposefully roll without knowing which number is on top. Also, I'm well aware of PRNGs quality. This is partially a question of curiosity, so I'm really only interested in true randomness and not really interested in requiring additional hardware because I want this program to be versatile. https://www.insidescience.org/news/dice-rolls-are-not-completely-random

Comment: From Python 3.6, use [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html). There are other crypto libraries for earlier versions.

Comment: That won't be enough entropy.